# Determining p,q from acf and pacf python

Tags: python, machine-learning, arima, autocorrelation

I'm having difficulties understanding how to determine `p` and `q` in ARIMA. What i understand is PACF cut off determines `p` and ACF hit very low determines `q` but at the same time the cut off in PACF which is determines `p` is equal to AR(q)? I'm still very confused. Then i tried it myself building ARIMA model and i get this ACF and PACF. And i assume that the `p` is 16 because it's cut off (hit zero abruptly) at lag 16. The `q` is 1 because it hits very low at lag 1. So my ARIMA order would be (16,0,1). Am i wrong? i learn it from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/sumi25/understand-arima-and-tune-p-d-q) and [here](https://dimensionless.in/beginners-guide-for-time-series-forecasting/). I don't know if i understand it right

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correlations which are within the blue bands are not statistically significant and so it doesn't look as though you have a model. There is a great tutorial here https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/tsa_arma_0.html on using Python for ARMA models.

Comment: Oh okay, i thought if i made the d = 0, then it would work with my ARMA model. I have read the content of the link you gave but i'm still confuse how to determine my `p` and `q` it does not explain the choosing of it

Comment: It's handy to know a few simple examples.: for an AR(1) model the ACF is an exponential whilst the PACFis non-zero only for lag=1. For a MA(1) model ACF is non-zero only for lag=1 whilst the PACF declines exponentially. A MA(2) model will only have the first two values of the ACF non-zero. Remember that the values of the ACF and PACF can be negative if there are negative coefficients in your model. Difference your data to create an ARIMA model if it looks like a random walk. Hope this helps.

Comment: alright, thank you so much for explaining it, have a nice day :)